# How to output values with ternary operation with three outcomes

Tags: javascript

I'm looping through an array of arrays. Each element has three values. The third value can be `High`, `Med`, or  `Low`

I would like to output

```
http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png for High
http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png for Med
http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png for Low
```

Here is what I have that works perfectly fine for when the value is `High` (outputs red) or outputs green.

```
for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][0], markers[i][1]);
    bounds.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        icon: markers[i][2] === 'High'? 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png' : 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
        map: map,
        title: "",
    });
}
```

**Question**

How can I make this work for `High, Med, Low` as described above?

Comment: That's going to produce very unreadable code. Why not just use if/else if and make the next developer who has to maintain this code not hate you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create simple map object:

```
var icons = {
    High: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png",
    Med: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png",
    Low: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png"
};
```

and use it like this:

```
for ( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][0], markers[i][1]);
    bounds.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        icon: icons[markers[i][2]],
        map: map,
        title: "",
    });
}
```

Comment: Ha, beat me by four seconds! :)

Comment: Yes, basically same time :)

Answer (score 4):

You could use an object:

```
var icons = {
    "High": "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png",
    "Med": "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png",
    "Low": "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png",
};
```

Then use `icon: icons[markers[i][2]]` or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

I understand it would not be a pretty read but in case you want to use **only ternary operator** , nest `(markers[i][2] === 'Med'? '': '')` condition for falsy condition of `markers[i][2] === 'High'?`.

```
icon: markers[i][2] === 'High'? 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png' 
: (markers[i][2] === 'Med'? 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png'
:'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png')
```

Comment: I was just going to post the same answer and found you already have answered... :)
bad luck :(

Comment: @RohitKumar Haha.. there is always a next time Rohit :)